# How to remove Show More/Show Less" link on User profile MyPage

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile, my-site, user-profile-property

On Userprofile myPage (Person.aspx), Some properties are show. But for some other properties We need to click on "Show More/Show less" link to view more properties. I want to remove this "Show More" link. How i do this: See below picture:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following CSS:

```
.ms-profile-toggleDetails {
    display:none;
}

.ms-profile-hiddenDetails {
    display:block !important;
    overflow:visible !important;
}
```

This will show all the information by default and hide "Show More" link button.

Comment: Ok!, But where i add this CSS? In which page and at what place?

Comment: It depends. If you are using a custom master page - you are probably using custom CSS files as well. You can add the code in any CSS file which is referenced in the master page. Otherwise you can add the CSS directly to the default master page, but changing out-of-the-box files are not recommended. Check the following resource on how to do this: http://changecase.net/blog/2014/03/28/add-custom-stylesheets-to-sharepoint/